# How to return entity object type from EntityType class in form?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine, entity, entitymanager

Every time I try to send data from form and use doctrine manager I have an error:
[image: Error]

As you can see, this problem is according to user_type. I have another entity UserType in which I have this attribute and I want to use it in register form.
I have controller and I want to add all form input into database and then error occurs.
I would like to point out that I don't want to get and set each attribute manually via for instance:

```
$name = $form['name']->getData();
$userDetails->setName($name);
```

Because I think that by using entity manager it is supposed to do automatically like this:
**UserController.php:**

```
 public function register(Request $request){
    $user = new User();
    $userType = new UserType();
    $userDetails = new UserDetails();
    $form = $this->createForm(RegisterFormType::class, $user);


    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted()){

        $userDetails = $form->getData();


        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($userDetails);
        $em->flush();
        dd($form->getData());
```

**My form in RegisterFormType.php:**

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            -> add('name',TextType::class,[
                'data_class' => UserDetails::class,
                'attr' => [
                    "placeholder" => 'Name'
                    ],
                ])
            -> add('surname',TextType::class,[
                'data_class' => UserDetails::class,
                'attr' => [
                    "placeholder" => 'Surname'
                ],
            ])
    
            ->add('email',TextType::class,[
                'attr' => [
                "placeholder" => 'Email'
            ]
            ])
            ->add('password',PasswordType::class,[
                'attr' => [
                    "placeholder" => 'Password'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('confirmPassword',PasswordType::class,[
                'attr' => [
                    "placeholder" => 'Confirm Password'
                ]
            ])
    
    
           /* ->add('user_type',ChoiceType::class, [
                'help' => 'Do you want to perform? Choose Artist account type. Do you want to employ artist? Choose Firm.',
                'label' => "Account type",
                'choices' => [
                    'None' => 0,
                    'firm' => 1,
                    'artist' => 2
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    "class" => 'choice'
                ]
    
            ])*/
           ->add('user_type',EntityType::class, [
               'class' => UserType::class,
               'choice_label'=>'type',
    
               /*'choice_label'=>'type',
               'choice_value' => function ($entity) {
                   return $entity ? $entity->getId() : '';
                   },*/
           ])
        ;
    }
    
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
    
        ]);
    }
```

After submitting input in form I get this data:
[image]

The problem is user_type sends as a string I suppose, but should as an object. Am I right?

**In User.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
     * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
     */
    class User extends UserDetails
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $id;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $email;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $password;
    
        private $confirmPassword;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=UserType::class, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
         */
        private $user_type;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=UserDetails::class, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
         */
        private $user_details;
    
    
        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=UserToOffert::class, mappedBy="user_", orphanRemoval=true)
         */
        private $user_to_offert;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Skill::class, mappedBy="user_", orphanRemoval=true)
         */
        private $skill;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Requirement::class, mappedBy="user_id", orphanRemoval=true)
         */
        private $requirement;
    
    
        public function __construct()
        {
    
            $this->user_to_offert = new ArrayCollection();
            $this->skill = new ArrayCollection();
            $this->requirement = new ArrayCollection();
    
        }
    
        public function getId(): ?int
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
    
        public function getEmail(): ?string
        {
            return $this->email;
        }
    
        public function setEmail(string $email): self
        {
            $this->email = $email;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getPassword(): ?string
        {
            return $this->password;
        }
    
        public function setPassword(string $password): self
        {
            $this->password = $password;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getUserType(): ?string
        {
            return $this->user_type;
        }
    
        public function setUserType(string $user_type): self
        {
            $this->user_type = $user_type;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getUserDetails(): ?UserDetails
        {
            return $this->user_details;
        }
    
        public function setUserDetails(UserDetails $user_details): self
        {
            $this->user_details = $user_details;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        /**
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getConfirmPassword()
        {
            return $this->confirmPassword;
        }
    
        /**
         * @param mixed $confirmPassword
         */
        public function setConfirmPassword($confirmPassword): void
        {
            $this->confirmPassword = $confirmPassword;
        }
    
    
    
    
    
        /**
         * @return Collection|UserToOffert[]
         */
        public function getUserToOffert(): Collection
        {
            return $this->user_to_offert;
        }
    
        public function addUserToOffert(UserToOffert $userToOffert): self
        {
            if (!$this->user_to_offert->contains($userToOffert)) {
                $this->user_to_offert[] = $userToOffert;
                $userToOffert->setUser($this);
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function removeUserToOffert(UserToOffert $userToOffert): self
        {
            if ($this->user_to_offert->removeElement($userToOffert)) {
                // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
                if ($userToOffert->getUser() === $this) {
                    $userToOffert->setUser(null);
                }
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        /**
         * @return Collection|Skill[]
         */
        public function getSkill(): Collection
        {
            return $this->skill;
        }
    
        public function addSkill(Skill $skill): self
        {
            if (!$this->skill->contains($skill)) {
                $this->skill[] = $skill;
                $skill->setUser($this);
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function removeSkill(Skill $skill): self
        {
            if ($this->skill->removeElement($skill)) {
                // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
                if ($skill->getUser() === $this) {
                    $skill->setUser(null);
                }
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        /**
         * @return Collection|Requirement[]
         */
        public function getRequirement(): Collection
        {
            return $this->requirement;
        }
    
        public function addRequirement(Requirement $requirement): self
        {
            if (!$this->requirement->contains($requirement)) {
                $this->requirement[] = $requirement;
                $requirement->setUser($this);
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function removeRequirement(Requirement $requirement): self
        {
            if ($this->requirement->removeElement($requirement)) {
                // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
                if ($requirement->getUser() === $this) {
                    $requirement->setUser(null);
                }
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
    
    
    }
```

**UserDetails.php:**

```
    <?php
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserDetailsRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserDetailsRepository::class)
 */
class UserDetails
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $photo;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSurname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    public function setSurname(string $surname): self
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getPhoto(): ?string
    {
        return $this->photo;
    }


    public function setPhoto(?string $photo): self
    {
        $this->photo = $photo;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->name;
    }


}
```

**In UserType.php:**

```
    <?php
namespace App\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserTypeRepository::class)
 */
class UserType
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $type;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getType(): ?string
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType(string $type): self
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return $this->type;
    }
}
```

If I remove __toString method I get an error:
[image: Error 2]

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Thank you for your time in advance. Have a nice day!

Comment: Can you show the content of UserDetails.php

Comment: Of course - done :)

Comment: It seems you are missing critical information in your entity (such as the namespace).... What version of symfony is this?

Comment: I use Symfony 5.2.4 . I have all of namespaces , but I didn't add them in this post. I will make an edit ;)

Comment: The first thing I see besides the missing code in your entities is that User Entity extends a UserDetails Entity, as far as I know an entity cannot extend another. You have to use Super for that https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses. Also that User entity has a OneToOne relation to UserDetails. I think you might be confused here.

Comment: Your user object UserType expects object and you are passing string, check getter setter method and chnage accordingly. Your data types should match everywhere.

Comment: @MaulikParmar  Yes, I know that it expects object instead of string, but the EntityType field returns always string. Is it any way to return object? My UserType setters and getters created automatically while creating ORM.